# Increase Windows installer-based Tomcat PermGen Space

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, grails

I'm having some problems with Tomcat. I'm deploying a Grails application and as I were adding new features I got this (sadly well known) error in the stacktrace file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2014-01-13 19:28:35,753 [http-bio-8080-exec-26] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at gsp_liquidaciones_liquidacionDeComplejolist_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_liquidaciones_liquidacionDeComplejolist_gsp.groovy:84)
    at gsp_liquidaciones_liquidacionDeComplejolist_gsp.run(gsp_liquidaciones_liquidacionDeComplejolist_gsp.groovy:105)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
...
```

I have an Windows installer-based tomcat installation and I don't have an catalina.bat file also. Googling many pages suggest to modify this file (catalina.bat) or register JAVA_OPTS variable, but nothing works. So, where do I have to specify this parameters?:

`SET JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC”`

I have tried to modify the Java Options through Apache Tomcat 7 Properties window but after the modifications the server can't start.

[image: tomcat java configuration tab]

My computer has 4Gb RAM installed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the following system specifications:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- 4 GB installed RAM
- Intel Core i7 processor
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)

The Tomcat 7 Java properties for an acceptable behavior MIGHT be:
[image: tomcat java configuration]

Answer (score 2):

You should have a small windows application 'tomcat6w.exe' or 'tomcat7w.exe' when tomcat was installed as a windows service. When you start this application it has a tab 'Java' where you can set the JVM parameters. For more details see [more memory to Tomcat service](http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2010/10/8/Giving-more-memory-to-the-Tomcat-Service-in-Windows).

You need to enter only the parameters which start with -X.

Comment: That's what I tried to do (I edited my post) but after the changes the server can't start.

Comment: There could be an error in the parameter list. Did you check the logs of the server? Set the level to debug in the logging tab for more information.

Comment: This is the last lines log in the tomcat7-stderr.2014-01-14 file:
`2014-01-14 19:48:29 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

This is the last lines log in the tomcat7-stdout.2014-01-14 file:
`2014-01-14 19:48:29 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap`

Do you think the values that I specified in the Java tab are appropriate according to my pc RAM?

Comment: Yes, I think the specified heap size is too high. See also this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654328/vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap

Comment: Thank you for the link, I read it but I think it won't help to solve my problem. Well after all I have my Tomcat installation working fine, at least for now. I think I've only postponed the problem. I will write the configurations I made as answer proposal.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me in **apache-tomcat-8.0.15**, but i think it would be the same for all to tomcat's version.

I had executed regedit and found this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tomcat8
```

And change ImagePath key to:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\bin\tomcat8.exe //RS//Tomcat8 ++JvmOptions -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```